# 1) What is the right sentence or both are accepted? and 2) Why is the sentence right in terms of grammar?

Tags: past-tense

1) It made their feeling of security more **match** the reality

2)  It made their feeling of security more **matched** the reality

from the [video](http://www.ted.com/talks/bruce_schneier/transcript?language=en#t-1191673)

Comment: Only the first sentence is correct.

Comment: @userr2684291
Thank you a lot. Would you please elaborate. I don't get it because all the sentence in a past simple although the verb 'match' the only in a present simple. Thank in advance

Comment: I think "match" isn't a present simple form, but an infinitive (without "to").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a causative verb, "make" can be followed by an object (a person or a thing) and a bare infinitive (infinitive without "to"). See these examples:

- Parents make their children **feel** secure.
- My parents made me **feel** secure when I was a child.
- Your will make your children **feel** secure if you encourage them properly.

As you can see, irrespective of the tense of "make" (present, past, future), the verb that follows the object (in this case, "children") is always in the infinitive: **feel**.

Simillarly, in the sentence at issue, we have "made" in the past and "match" in the infinitive:

- It made their feeling of security more **match** the reality.

(This means: It caused their feeling of security to be more in line with reality, or to be more realistic. Notice that with the verb "cause" we use "to"- infinitive.)